# find non-overlapping blocks in a list

Tags: python, list, merge

I have a list:
x = [[**263**, 3121], [2201, 4756], [3145, 6423], [4765, **8165**], [**12480**, 18421], [18000, **24191**], [**26343**, 28105], [27341, **28912**], [**29497**, **30282**]]

I want a new list that contains the merged overlapping blocks (highlighted above in bold):
y = [[263,8165],[12480,24191],[26343,28912],[29497,30282]]

That is, to go through the x-list and merge all overlapping lists to give y.   If the first item of the next item of the list in x is smaller than the last item of the previous item in x, then merge the two and save to y, otherwise don't merge just put the new starting value as the next item in y.  Continue through x until all overlapping blocks are merged and written into y.

Thank you for your help

Comment: why has this question been downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write down the code just as you described it in the text.

```
def yield_data(data):
    start = None
    end = None
    for entry in sorted(data):
        if start is None:
            start = entry[0]
        if end is None or entry[0] < end:
            end = entry[1]
        else:
            yield [start, end]
            start, end = entry
    yield [start, end]


def main():
    x = [[263, 3121], [2201, 4756], [3145, 6423], [4765, 8165], [12480, 18421],
         [18000, 24191], [26343, 28105], [27341, 28912], [29497, 30282]]
    for group in yield_data(x):
        print(group)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The compares to `None` are used to initialize the data in the first loop.